# Splunk Alerts to slack not working

Tags: webhooks, splunk, slack-api, alerts

I have currently set some basic alerts on Splunk my requirement is that, whenever these alerts get raised, I should receive them on Slack. I have an incoming webhook set up for my slack channel and an ordinary POST message from my server (where Splunk is running) successfully reaches my slack channel. However, when the Splunk alert is generated it does not get sent to my Slack Channel even though I have already set it up to send it to the required webhook. Any insights on where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I had a firewall issue apparently